# Understanding 照相 and 照片

Tags: word-choice, characters, difference, etymology, word

I am having some confusion about 照相 and 照片. In my Chinese lesson they introduced them:

> 照片
>
> Zhào piàn
>
> (noun) photo

> 照相
>
> Zhào xiàng
>
> (verb) to take a picture

They also showed this *example*:

> 我**照**了几百张**照片**。
>
> I took several hundreds of photos.

**Question:**

Is the first 照 of the example the short of 照相? Though 照相照片 (*take a picture picture*) sounds redundant...

Or 照照片 is just another way to express 照相? This also seems strange to me as 照 is duplicated.

---

I tried to understand the words by the characters (from [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php)):

- 照: to illuminate, to reflect
- 片: slice, film
- 相: appearance, portrait, picture

This confuses me because both 片 and 相 have similar meanings.

Comment: Heuristically, 照 is the transitive version, expecting (in the sense of "take [a picture]") an object, possibly delayed; 照相 is the intransitive version, already incorporating the implied object within the word itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the first 照 of the example the short of 照相? Though 照相照片 (take a picture picture) sounds redundant...

No, 照 is not short of 照相, so  照相照片 is wrong.

> Or 照照片 is just another way to express 照相? This also seems strange to
> me as 照 is duplicated

Yes, 照照片 is fine because 照片 is a noun meaning *photo*  and 照 is a verb meaning *take;shoot;photogragh*.

照相 can be taken as the shorthand of 照相片.  相片 is a noun meaning *照片;photo*. So, both 照照片 and 照相片 are correct.

Comment: Maybe etymologily 照片 means *photo* because 照 means *reflected / illuminated* and 片 *film*; as analogical cameras had to *develop the film*. So 照照片 could be understood as *to illuminate (shoot) the illuminating film*.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that 照相 is a noun, and should be interpreted as the action to take a picture: 我們去照相 （We go to take pictures.）In this context, you can use 拍照 in lieu of 照相。And it can be separated as a verb and a noun: 我**拍**了几张**照** or 我**照**了几张**相**。

To summarize:

- 照片 = (noun) photo
- 照相、拍照 = (noun) the action to take pictures
- 我**照**了几张**相**、我**拍**了几张**照**

  - 照、拍 = (verb) to take a picture
  - 相、照 = (noun) photo

Furthermore, when the context is clear enough (i.e. talking about taking pictures), you can use independently 照/拍 as a verb:

> 你照/拍了嗎？ = 你拍照/照相了嗎？

Beware that 照/拍 alone have different meanings, that's why the context should be clear enough to use them alone.